# Using sessions in Espresso Framework

Tags: ruby

good progress so far.
got all controllers and actions up and running in matter of minutes.

However not sure how make sessions work.

trying:

```
class Cart
    session :memory

    # my actions
end
```

but it fails with an error that say to use sessions at app level.

how that? where is that app level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are starting the app like this:

```
Cart.run
```

it is a good one unless you need to add some setup to your app.

creating app is as easy as:

```
app = EApp.new :automount
app.run
```

and if you have some setup for the app, use a block at initialization:

```
app = EApp.new :automount do
    session :memory
end
app.run
```

Please note the first argument - `:automount` - it instructs the app to search for controllers and mount them automatically.

If you want to mount your controllers manually, omit first argument:

```
app = EApp.new do
    session :memory
end
app.mount Cart
app.run
```